# How to get the physical path of a file that is in a virtual drive from C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

The problem is posed in the following way:

I create a virtual drive or "virtual drive letter" with a command in DOS called subst by means of a bat like this:

```
@echo off
cd \
subst J: /D
subst J: C:\Virtual_Disk\Unit_J
```

In the list of windows units I see the unit created,in which I placed some files and an executable. I am currently developing a program in c # where it calls the path of the executable that is in the virtual path, and suddenly, an exception is thrown that indicates that the path of the executable is not found even though the executable is there, I look at the properties of the executable. executable and in the field location indicates the virtual path of that executable but not the physical route. If I was not clear, I will give an example:

(1) virtual path of the executable

```
J:\Program\executable.exe
```

(2) physical route where the executable is located

```
C:\Virtual_Disks\Unit_J\Program\executable.exe
```

C# captures the virtual path of the executable (1) but not where it really is (2).

Not being more, I appreciate the help provided.

Comment: what is the return value of `System.IO.File.Exists(string path)` ?

Comment: I know you can do this for mapped network drives (using the Win32_MappedLogicalDisk WMI class), but I can't seem to find one for subst mappings. You might have to run "subst" with no parameters to list mappings, but capture the output in your program, and then parse it for future detection.

Comment: Unless you have a specific question about the editor, Visual Studio, Visual studio means nothing. What version of .Net are you targeting?

Comment: This is not so unusual, the SUBST command is a parlor trick that the native OS knows nothing about.  The Process class can easily be a troublemaker, it uses a backdoor into the native OS to get process info.  You need to post the stack trace of the exception and a snippet of the code that generates it to get real help.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e43cc927-4bcc-42d7-9630-f5fdfdb4a1fa/get-absolute-path-of-drive-mapped-to-local-folder):

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern uint QueryDosDevice(string lpDeviceName, StringBuilder lpTargetPath, int ucchMax);

    private static string GetPhysicalPath(string path)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("path");
        }

        // Get the drive letter
        var pathRoot = Path.GetPathRoot(path);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pathRoot))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("path");
        }

        var substPrefix = @"\??\";
        var lpDeviceName = pathRoot.Replace(@"\", string.Empty);            
        var lpTargetPath = new StringBuilder(260);
        if (QueryDosDevice(lpDeviceName, lpTargetPath, lpTargetPath.Capacity) != 0)
        {
            string result;

            // If drive is substed, the result will be in the format of "\??\C:\RealPath\".
            if (lpTargetPath.ToString().StartsWith(substPrefix))
            {
                // Strip the \??\ prefix.
                var root = lpTargetPath.ToString().Remove(0, substPrefix.Length);
                result = Path.Combine(root, path.Replace(Path.GetPathRoot(path), string.Empty));
            }

            else
            {
                // if not SUBSTed, just assume it's not mapped.
                result = path;
            }

            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```